# NameError: name 'users' is not defined in python django

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm sorry if this question has been repeatedly asked but I hope that you kindly help me to figure out what is the problem here.
I'm following a python crash course book that uses old versions of Django.

I've set up a app called 'users' in my setting so users can make accounts of their own.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #my apps
    'learning_logs',
    'users',
]
```

and I've included the path in my urls file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

app_name = 'learning_logs'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', users.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

and this is the error that I get:

```
NameError: name 'users' is not defined
```

and if I do it like this
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

```
app_name = 'learning_logs'

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

I get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.urls'
```

thank you so much for your time and response!

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of PCC. For future reference, you can see the code for the project [here](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e). Here's what the [urls.py file](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/blob/master/chapter_19/setting_up_user_accounts/learning_log/urls.py) should look like at this point in the project. The project was originally written with Django 2.2, but I keep the book up to date with each new printing, and everything in the second edition still works at this time.

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

I think this line is causing problems. You need to add 'users.url' inside quotes or else it won't be able to find these urls.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that there is a 'urls.py' file in your app.

What you are doing here is that you are trying to make a new url file inside your app so that it will be 'www.your.domain/users/**the_url_choose**' and to do this you must have a urls.py file instide your app (the folder names 'users')

Inside that urls file you have to copy exactly the main urls file and change it according to your needs for easy site routing

Comment: this was precisely the error.......... thank you so much for your answer

Comment: you are welcome bro!
can you just accept it as the answer so any other person having the same problem can solve it.
and upvote plz :)